# When i run .bashrc to create alias the a in alias is replaced with an '

Tags: bash, alias

When I log into a shell i have a .bashrc that builds multiple alias for me.

for example

alias test='~/script/test'

when this runs it creates the following alias:

'lias test='~/script/test'

For some reason the a in alias is replaces with an ' and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: You have a carriage return at the end of the value -- an invisible character that sends the cursor back to the beginning of the current line when printed.

Comment: ...that makes your command `alias test='~/script/test'` behave identically to `alias test='~/script/test'$'\r'`.

Comment: By the way, `test` is an unfortunate choice of names, since that name is also used for a shell builtin.

Comment: ...as another aside, this is literally given as the *very first thing to check before you ask a question* in the bash tag wiki at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `dos2unix` on your `.bashrc`.

Right now, it has Windows newlines -- meaning that every endline has two characters, `<CR>` and `<LF>`. `CR` sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line when it's printed (whereas `LF` sends the cursor down to the next line); thus, the `'` at the end of the output from `alias` for that line shows up at the beginning of the line when printed to a terminal.